# Use of unresolved identifier using selector

Tags: ios, swift

I have been getting this error `Use of unresolved identofier 'rightBarButtonDidClick'`.

I have already declared the class of `rightBarButtonDidClick`, 
But why its showing the error? 
As per previous post on same topics, I tried every possible solutions 
Like checking target membership and all. Its all okay . 
Here is the Full code

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @objc func rightBarButtonDidClick() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, Logout", style: .destructive, handler: {
            alert -> Void in
            SyncUser.current?.logOut()
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([WelcomeViewController()], animated: true)
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class ItemsViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm: Realm
    let items: Results<Item>

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        let syncConfig = SyncConfiguration(user: SyncUser.current!, realmURL: Constants.REALM_URL)
        self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: syncConfig, objectTypes:[Item.self]))
        self.items = realm.objects(Item.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "timestamp", ascending: false)
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonDidClick))
    }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

I am using `Swift` `4.2` `Xcode` `10.0`

Comment: both are different class, you are created the method in `ItemsViewController` but you invoked the function call in  `ViewController`

Comment: Move `func rightBarButtonDidClick()` to `ItemsViewController ` class or 
inherit `ItemsViewController` from `ViewController`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thank you. I was folliwing a tutorial, He didnt mention anything like this. That error is gone now. Thank you

Comment: welcome .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this method `rightBarButtonDidClick` into `ItemsViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}

class ItemsViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm: Realm
    let items: Results<Item>

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        let syncConfig = SyncConfiguration(user: SyncUser.current!, realmURL: Constants.REALM_URL)
        self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: syncConfig, objectTypes:[Item.self]))
        self.items = realm.objects(Item.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "timestamp", ascending: false)
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonDidClick))
    }

    @objc func rightBarButtonDidClick() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, Logout", style: .destructive, handler: {
            alert -> Void in
            SyncUser.current?.logOut()
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([WelcomeViewController()], animated: true)
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 }
```